# ntp sync date/time failure causes Zk cleanup procedure not to remove client sessions

Tags: session, zk, apache-zookeeper

If for any reason the ntp sync. date/time looses the correct time and the cluster changes to a future date/time then the created client sessions in Zk will not be removed after 10 minutes if meanwhile the date/time of cluster is again synced to the correct date/time.

Now my assumption is that  zookeeper clean procedure is activated (every 10 minutes) in the crontabs but is cleaning sessions that are in the past only!!!

0-59/10 * * * * /opt/dve/bin/zookeeper_cleanup.sh

So there is no way to clean those sessions created in the future but only going Back to the future on the same date and wait until the zookeeper_cleanup.sh cleans the session after 10 minutes.

i tried to remove the log files,but it may not the right way,may be it will cause other problem.
so what i should do is better.

Answer (score 0):

```
For last ,we remove the log by zookeeper api.as:

Stat stat = null;
List<String> children = this.zooKeeper.getChildren(tempSessionPath, false, stat);
System.out.println(children.size() + " sessions found.");
int count = 0;
for(String child:children){
  String path = this.tempSessionPath + "/" + child;
  stat = this.zooKeeper.exists(path, false);
  if(null != stat && stat.getCtime() > currentTime){
  count++;
  System.out.println("Session created in future time " + stat.getCtime() + " to be deleted!");
  safeDeleteZKNode(path, stat);
  }
}
System.out.println(count + " future sessions cleaned!");
```